# Build and Deploy C# Net Framework in GitLab CI CD

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gitlab, yaml, cicd

Asking very generally as I am completely new to Gitlabs CI/CD and CI/CD in general.

I have implemented a C# Net Framework application in Visual Studio 2017 and manage it with Gitlab.
Now I want to automatically create a binary of that application with the GitLab CI/CD feature.

I already have a runner ( docker based on Windows) registered in GitLab and run jobs.
My current YAML file looks as following:

```yaml
    default:
      image: ruby:2.7.2
    
    
    
    job:
      stage: build
      only:
        - branches
      script:
        - set -m
        - echo "Start build"
         - '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Release /clp:ErrorsOnly; Build "NameOfApplication.sln"'
      artifacts:
        expire_in : 1 days
        paths:
          - '.\IndoorNavigation\bin\Release'
```

How can I now get the artifact / binary MSBuild generates? It should show up in pipelines for download right? I already tried the artifacts option with different path unsuccessfully.

Would also be happy for links to good tutorials as I have not found any tutorial that helped me.

Edit: Output of the Job:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.3.1 (8b63c432)
  on docker-runner 2tZDZ6cX
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.7.2 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.7.2 ...
Using docker image sha256:e6c92ed2f03be9788b80944e148783bef8e7d0fa8d9755b62e9f03429e85a327 for ruby:2.7.2 with digest ruby@sha256:1dd0106849233fcd913b7c4608078fa1a53a5e3ce1af2a55e4d726b0d8868e2f ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-2tzdz6cx-project-1235-concurrent-0 via d98bb3402720...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/user/NameOfApplication/.git/
Checking out 2e50e922 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
Using docker image sha256:e6c92ed2f03be9788b80944e148783bef8e7d0fa8d9755b62e9f03429e85a327 for ruby:2.7.2 with digest ruby@sha256:1dd0106849233fcd913b7c4608078fa1a53a5e3ce1af2a55e4d726b0d8868e2f ...
$ set -m
$ echo "Start build" - '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Release /clp:ErrorsOnly; Build "NameOfApplication.sln"'
Start build - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Release /clp:ErrorsOnly; Build "NameOfApplication.sln"
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:01
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: .\NameOfApplication\bin\Release: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

Comment: What is the output in the CI/CD? I do not think you could  run c:\.. command in a linux based docker container( ruby:2.7.2)

Comment: I'd echo Atilla here in asking for some CI/CD output, and mention that the `artifacts` keyword is exactly the correct way of doing what you're asking for. You've mentioned it hasn't worked for you though, so please show us a configuration you've tried with the artifacts keyword that hasn't worked. My guess is the binary is being placed somewhere in the container that isn't where you're expecting.

Comment: @Patrick  I added the config I used with the artifacts keyword and the respective output of the job.

Comment: @AtillaOzgur I added the config I used with the artifacts keyword and the respective output of the job.

Comment: Same error if you just use `IndoorNavigation\bin\Release` as path? (or `NameOfApplication\bin\Release`, there's is a mismatch between configuration and output). Also there's is an indentation issue in the `script` configuration block but mqybe it's just a copy&paste issue. Have you tried using the unix path syntax?

Comment: Yeah, agreed with @DavideMadrisan here - it's going to be something in the config of your artifacts block, because your CI is succeeding then finding no file. When you run the same command locally, where does it put the artifact? You may also want to try using some wildcards in your artifact syntax as right now you're pulling in the whole directory if it succeeds, but we can work on that once the directory name is right.